# What Rust type to store binary data in a PDA?

Tags: anchor

I have some binary data - about 1KB - to be stored in a PDA. The Anchor program doesn't need to read or process this data, just store it.

I've attempted to use a Rust array of 1 byte elements of size 1024 to store this.

```
pub fn doThing(
    context: Context<DoThingAccountConstraints>,
    id: u64,
    data: [u8; 1024],
) -> Result<()> {
    ...
}
```

My understanding that the appropriate TS type is `Array<Number>`:

```
// A 1024 byte array filled with the JS number 1.
const data = Array(1024).fill(1);

const transactionSignature = await program.methods.doThing
      .myprogram(id, data)
      .rpc();
```

This fails with:

```
  RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 999. Received 1000
```

**What is the Rust type and matching TS type I should use to send bytes as part of a Solana instruction?**

**Edit:** I suspect `[u8; someSize]` (Rust) and `Array<number>` TS is correct, but there's a limit on transaction size. Since if I set `someSize` to be, say 950, the `ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE` goes away and `anchor test` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering this myself to help others, if someone else comes along with a better answer I'll mark that as preferred instead.*

`[u8; someSize]` (Rust) and `Array<number>` TS is correct.

I suspect **`ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE` is a transaction size limit issue**

Since if I set `someSize` to be, say 950, the `ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE` goes away and `anchor test` completes.

Per [the Solana docs](https://solana.com/docs/programs/deploying):

> Writes are processed in small chunks due to a limitation of Solana transactions having a maximum serialized size of 1232 bytes.

Comment: You can also try `Uint8Array` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array -- it's pretty much the exact same thing as its Rust counterpart!

Answer (score 2):

TS may complain about the type, but `number[]` is acceptable.

Similarly when you want to read data from that space you can cast it as a buffer with something like `let buff = Buffer.from(someAcc.data)` or `let buff = Buffer.from(someAcc.data as any as number[])` if TS doesn't like the typing and read slices like:
`let someBN = new BN(buff.slice(0, 0 + 24), undefined, "le"),`

Likewise for writing values to be passed to an ix, a number[] made from your data's buffer.

Comment: Thanks! Per the edit I'm indeed using `Array<number>` (AKA `number[]`) but it looks like this is actually a transaction / instruction size limit issue.